# while I'm retrieving the tabular format data using JSON data into PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I'm trying to get data into the tabular format by invoking JSON data into PHP code.

JSON code written to use for converting into tabular format.

```
[

  {
   "#":"3586 "
   "Project" :"SSMT",
   "Tracker" :"Maintenance",
   "Status" : "To Do"
   "Subject" : "Test the following scenario and provide the relevant scripts in centos7"
   "Author" : "Anil K"
   "Assignee" : "SSMT Group"
  },
  {
   "#" :"3517"
   "Project" : "SSMT"
   "Tracker" : "Improvement"
   "Status" : "In Progress"
   "Subject" : "Image server daily backup"
   "Author" : "Lakshmi G"
   "Assignee" : "Pooja S"
  },
  {
   "Project" : "SSMT"
   "Tracker" : "Improvement"
   "Status" : "In Progress"
   "Subject" : "setup openstack all-in-one in centos7 instance on ORAVM1 box."
   "Author" : "Anil K"
   "Assignee" : "Bhanuprakash P"
  }
]
```

The below php code is written to fetch the above JSON data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-US">

<?php

$url = 'data.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_decode($data);

echo $characters[0]->name;

foreach ($characters as $character) {
         echo $character->name . '<br>';

}
?>

 <table>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Project</th>
                        <th>Tracker</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Assignee</th>

                </tr>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($characters as $character) {
                                echo '<tr>'
                                echo '<td>' . $character-># . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $character->project . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $character->tracker . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $character->status . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $character->subject . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $character->author . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $character->assignee . '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
        </tbody>

 </table>

</html>
```

**I received following error
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/html/tabularformat.php on line 34`**

can anyone suggest othis? ?

after adding ; at the end of each 'echo' statement. also getting the same error. please find it.

Comment: add `;`  after each `echo` statement completed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: added ; semi-comma and the result is same.

Comment: check your key it will not `#` for sure

Comment: change the  name `#`. `#` cannot be a variable,function name in php.

Comment: please find the above json data the key value is  `#`.

Answer (score 0):

- I recommend using `true` as the second parameter to form array elements.
- Your json is invalid (I fixed it in my code)
- You need to access the keys case-sensitively.
- Check that an element exists before trying to access it.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aec630ae4e2e990c084eb1a7b92df42605da9b17))

```
$json='[
  {
   "#":"3586 ",
   "Project" :"SSMT",
   "Tracker" :"Maintenance",
   "Status" : "To Do",
   "Subject" : "Test the following scenario and provide the relevant scripts in centos7",
   "Author" : "Anil K",
   "Assignee" : "SSMT Group"
  },
  {
   "#" :"3517",
   "Project" : "SSMT",
   "Tracker" : "Improvement",
   "Status" : "In Progress",
   "Subject" : "Image server daily backup",
   "Author" : "Lakshmi G",
   "Assignee" : "Pooja S"
  },
  {
   "Project" : "SSMT",
   "Tracker" : "Improvement",
   "Status" : "In Progress",
   "Subject" : "setup openstack all-in-one in centos7 instance on ORAVM1 box.",
   "Author" : "Anil K",
   "Assignee" : "Bhanuprakash P"
  }
]';

$characters = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($characters as $character) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['#'])?$character['#']:''),'</td>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['Project'])?$character['Project']:''),'</td>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['Tracker'])?$character['Tracker']:''),'</td>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['Status'])?$character['Status']:''),'</td>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['Subject'])?$character['Subject']:''),'</td>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['Author'])?$character['Author']:''),'</td>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character['Assignee'])?$character['Assignee']:''),'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Output:

```
<tr>
    <td>3586 </td>
    <td>SSMT</td>
    <td>Maintenance</td>
    <td>To Do</td>
    <td>Test the following scenario and provide the relevant scripts in centos7</td>
    <td>Anil K</td>
    <td>SSMT Group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3517</td>
    <td>SSMT</td>
    <td>Improvement</td>
    <td>In Progress</td>
    <td>Image server daily backup</td>
    <td>Lakshmi G</td>
    <td>Pooja S</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>SSMT</td>
    <td>Improvement</td>
    <td>In Progress</td>
    <td>setup openstack all-in-one in centos7 instance on ORAVM1 box.</td>
    <td>Anil K</td>
    <td>Bhanuprakash P</td>
</tr>
```

---

Otherwise, you can use "encapsulation" to access the `#` object.

```
$characters = json_decode($json);
foreach ($characters as $character) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>',(isset($character->{'#'})?$character->{'#'}:''),'</td>';
        // ...
```

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> Example #2 Accessing invalid object properties
>
> Accessing elements within an object that contain characters not permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the apostrophe.
>
> ```
> $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';
>
> $obj = json_decode($json);
> print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
> ```